# Office365 push notification API error: verification failed because the response body

Tags: php, outlook-restapi

I am referring to [o365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations) API documentation for adding push notification of calendar event. I am getting below error-
Post>>

```
array:4 [▼
  "@odata.type" => "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription"
  "Resource" => "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events"
  "NotificationURL" => "https://mywebsite.com/notifications"
  "ChangeType" => "Created,Updated"
]
Response>>
"{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidParameter","message":"Notification URL 'https://mywebsite.com/notifications?validationtoken=ODFkNDllYWEtMmExYi00NDVjLWJmNzUtOTBhZjg3MDAyNjhh' verification failed because the response body '\tsuccess\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000' is unexpected."}} ◀"
```

My code is as-

```
$post_data = [          "@odata.type"=> "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
   "Resource"=>  "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events",
   "NotificationURL"=>  'https://mywebsite.com/notification',  
   "ChangeType"=>  "Created,Updated",
  // "expirationDateTime"=>  "2018-05-09T18:23:45.9356913Z",
  // "clientState"=> "testClientState"

  ];
   $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions",
    //CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post_data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        // Set Here Your Requesred Headers
        'Authorization: Bearer '.TOKEN,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN: TOKEN-XXXXX'

    ),
));
```

How can I resolve the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notification endpoint must respond to a validation POST in a very specific way. Your response doesn't match that way, so the validation is failing.

From https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks:

Microsoft Graph validates the notification URL in a subscription request before creating the subscription. The validation process occurs as follows:

1. Microsoft Graph sends a POST request to the notification URL:

   ```
   POST https://{notificationUrl}?validationToken={TokenDefinedByMicrosoftGraph}
   ClientState: {Data sent in ClientState value in subscription request (if any)}
   ```
2. The client must provide a response with the following characteristics within 10 seconds:

   - A 200 (OK) status code.
   - The content type must be text/plain.
   - The body must include the validation token provided by Microsoft Graph.

The client should discard the validation token after providing it in the response.

Comment: Thanks Jason. It works for me. I am facing another issue- when I am trying to connect with 'admin' account it works fine, but when try to connect with 'normal user' account it returns empty response. Any idea, why this could be?

Comment: No, sorry. You might want to start a new post for that with more details.